# composite UniqueConstraint and on_conflict_do_nothing don't combine?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a database with a table that has a composite unique constraint. So the table in flask-sqlalchemy looks something like this:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(80))
   collection = db.Column(db.String(80))
   entry_type = db.Column(db.String(80))

   __table_args__ = (
       db.UniqueConstraint(name, collection),
   )
```

Now I want to be able to insert several rows at a time, but my input could have duplicates, so I wanted the unique constraint to protect me.
I found that sqlite has an option for `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, so I tried to do this with flask-sqlalchemy.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66958910/4981674) stackoverflow answer and the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#insert-on-conflict-upsert), what I have done so far is:

```
my_vals = (id, name, collection, entry_type)
insert_command = insert(MyModel.__table__).values(my_vals).on_conflict_do_update(
    index_elements=(MyModel.name, MyModel.collection))
db.session.execute(insert_command)
db.session.commit()
```

However, I keep getting `(IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: mymodel.name, mymodel.collection`
and I can see the resulting sqlite command and the `ON CONFLICT` part is not added.

If I write: `on_conflict_do_update(index_elements=(MyModel.name,))`
I get `OperationError ON CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint` but the `ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING` part is added to the sqlite command.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug? The [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.Insert.on_conflict_do_nothing) clearly states that the method expects a sequence, so why doesn't it work for more than one column?

PS: Please ignore any typos, the code is in another computer that has no access to internet.